# Click the imageview that is in the listview to go to another activity

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

There is a imageview and a textview in a listview.
I want to click the imageview to go to another activity with the value of the hashmap. I uesed setOnItemClickListener is as below:

```
    lvAll.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long arg3) {
            testBadgeMap = (HashMap<String, Object>) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
        }
    });
```

But I can't set the listener for the imageview in order I can't click the imageview.
How can I click the imageview to go to another activity with the value of hashmap?

Comment: You have to put the **setOnClickListener** method in **getview** of adapter for the **imageview**.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Adapter code to handle the click within the list items.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView,
        ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) con
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourlayout, parent, false);

    Button row = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.btnSample);


    final int n = position;
    row.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent next = new Intent(context, NextActivity.class);
                startActivity(next);

        }
    });

    return rowView;
}
```

Comment: How can I get the value of the hashmap if I do like this? I put some value in the map, I need these infomation in the next activity

Answer (score 0):

you can use image.setOnClickListener() 
but i suggest to use ImageButton,it's extends from imageView ,it will Interception click event,then you can click it

Answer (score 0):

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View row = convertView;
        RecordHolder holder = null;

        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)mcontext).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, parent, false);
            holder = new RecordHolder();

            holder.tv_name=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);

    holder.btn_custom_delete=(Button) row.findViewById(R.id.btn_custom_delete);

    holder.btn_custom_insert=(Button) row.findViewById(R.id.btn_custom_insert);

           row.setTag(holder);
         } else {
           holder = (RecordHolder) row.getTag();
         }

                    holder.tv_name.setTag(position);
                    holder.btn_custom_delete.setTag(position);

                    holder.tv_name.setText(getItem(position));

                    holder.tv_name.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            int pos = (Integer) view.getTag();

                            Intent intent = new Intent(mcontext , ActionActivity.class);
                            // Here You can also get you position of arraylist or hashmap by pos i.e integer variable value.

                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    });                   

                    return row;
}
```